# Alternative method for contour integration (along a non-closed curve)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm given the function $\frac{1}{z^2-4}$ and asked to evaluate it along the  following contour:
[image: contour]

To do so, I did a partial fractions decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{z^2-4}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z+2} \right)$$

and added the oriented line segment starting at $-2i$ and ending at $2i$. From here, I calculated this integral by taking the antiderivative, since the curve is in a domain:
$$\log(2i-2)-\log(2i+2)-\log(-2i-2)+\log(2-2i)$$
which gave a total of $\pi i$, so dividing by $4$ gives $i \pi/4$.

Applying the residue theorem, it looks like the total integral should be $-i \pi$, since we go around one pole counterclockwise, and the other clockwise, so we add them, and subtracting the difference gives $-i\pi \pi i -i \pi/4=-3 i \pi/4$.

However, I don't like this for two reasons:

1. It took a long time, and due to the number of steps, I think I'm prone to mistakes.
2. It doesn't help with slightly different functions such as $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ which I also asked to solve

Is there a faster, and more methodological way to approach these types of problems?

Comment: Contour looks symmetric. Maybe can be used

Comment: That was my first impression as well, but I didn't really know how to utilize that meaningfully.

Comment: It was probably too long ago I did this to try and help with more than first idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your approach. Every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms.

Consider the first half of the path (from $2i$ to $0$), Turn it into a loop going in straight line from $0$ to $2i$. You can compute the integral along this loop using Cauchy's integral theorem. And the integral along the line segment that you've added is easily computed directly from the definition. So, this gives you the integral along the first half of the path.

Now, do the same thing with second half.

Comment: Yes, but assuming we pick a section appropriately, this shouldn't be a problem, right? In reality the first time I did it, I used an explicit parametrization of the segment and computed that instead, but I think that was silly. I also cannot see how your approach is different from mine

Comment: are you suggesting that I just ignore the partial fraction part of the method above?

Comment: I see no gain in using partial fraction decomposition. And my answer doesn't use logarithms in an ambiguous way.

Comment: It seems to me that the computation of the line segment is where I use the logarithm function. Does computing first $0$ to $2i$ and then $-2i$ to $0$ eliminate said ambiguity?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you go from $0$ to $2i$ or if you go from $-2i$ to $2i$. If you compute from the definition, you'll get a number which has a logarithm, yes, but it is the logarithm of a real number greater than $0$.

Comment: Could one not make it unambiguous by demanding that we use a branch that varies continuously from the start of $C$ until the end? Your point is taken, that as written, but in the first computation for $\frac{1}{z-2}$ we can take the section starting at $\pi/2$ say, and then $\Delta \theta$ is well defined, since $\theta$ is continuous, and in the second computatation take a different branch.

Comment: Although, I'm interested in your words, I'll give the computation a shot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mbox{Above}:\,\,\,\,\, & \phantom{-\,\,\,\,}2\pi\ic\,\mrm{Res}\pars{{1 \over z^{2} - 4},z = - 2} - \int_{0}^{2}{\ic\,\dd y \over -y^{2} - 4}
\\[5mm]
\mbox{Bellow}:\,\,\,\,\, & -2\pi\ic\,\mrm{Res}\pars{{1 \over z^{2} - 4},z = \phantom{-}2} - \int_{-2}^{0}{\ic\,\dd y \over -y^{2} - 4}
\\[5mm]
\mbox{Result}:\,\,\,\,\, & 2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 2\pars{-2}} - 2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 2\pars{2}}  + 2\ic\int_{0}^{2}{\dd y \over y^{2} + 4}= \bbx{-\,{3\pi \over 4}\,\ic}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I still don't see how I could generalize this for the case of $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$. Would the idea be to also find a different segment to "complete" this contour and do as you do above?

Comment: Are you sure that $-i \pi$ is correct?

Comment: @AndresMejia I just rechecked my answer. Thanks.